# How to find dynamic text when xpath is same for all --- Selenium Python testing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium Python testing -- xpath same but the text is changing to "error" and "success" -- I need to identify "success" and "error" message, how to do this ---please help me out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1QeS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fwht.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit unclear on exactly you want to achive.

If you want to have the titel in the modal, that either would be "Success" or "Error":

```
//h4[@class="modal-titel"]/text()
```

This assumes that there will only be one `h4` element with class `modal-title` on the page.

`//`, anywhere on the document

`h4[@class="modal-titel"]`, a `h4` element with `class` attribute set to `modal-titel`, if this element could have other classes, it should be `h4[contains(@class, "modal-titel")]`

`text()`, the matched node text value

If instead you want the message in the modal, you could use:

```
//div[@class="modal-body"]/text()
```